# How to make custom scope acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I have Profile model, I have Tags (skills and interests) made with ActsAsTaggableOn

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag (id, name, created_at, tag_count)

ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging(id, tag_id, tagger_type, tagger_id, context, created_at,taggable_type, taggable_id)
```

How do I sort skills by name through the model relationship?
It should look something like this:

`has_many :publications_desc, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(30) }, class_name: 'Publication'`

Answer (score 0):

Yo, seems I found solution for me

```
has_many :named_thing, lambda {
    'do what you want'
  }, through: :taggings, source: :tag
```